# Print out Images without Preview Dialog C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to print images in c#. I send a new job to default printer using `PrintQueue.AddJob` however everytime I get this preview dialog from Windows here I have do decided how image shall be printer (e.g. image stretched to page size or half page...)

How can I turn this dialog off? I want to silently print the images without this annoying dialog?

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like printer specific tool, which detects images sent to be printed and allow certain manipulations with them. If you don't need it, then do not install that tool (or perhaps there is a way to disable it). It has nothing to do with .Net or C#.

Comment: @Sinatr what? no! I am taking path of image and send it to printer. What tool you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the methode [overload of AddJob with a PrintTicket object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973165.aspx) .
Maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: Sounds good. Which of the settings shall I set in PrintTicket?

Comment: I have never used it before. There is no property like silent mode. I hope just using this will solve. I cant try it here.